# excel formula to get unique entries by week number

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a excel sheet with a log of access dates,email addresses, and week number (calculated from access date). I can count the number of times the system was accessed the previous week using the formula
`=COUNTIF(Table1[weeknum],WEEKNUM(TODAY())-1)`

As a person may access the system multiple times I need to see how many unique users accessed the system the previous week. Using the formula below I can see all the unique users, but how can I get this to only show last weeks unique users?

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(Table1[Email],Table1[Email]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of Excel supports the `FILTER` and `UNIQUE` functions, you can try the following formula:

```xls
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[email],(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-1)=Table1[Weeknumber])))
```

- `FILTER(Table1[email],(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-1)=Table1[Weeknumber])`: filters the email addresses based on week numbers.
- `UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[email],(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-1)=Table1[Weeknumber]))`: gets unique filtered emails
- `COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[email],(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-1)=Table1[Weeknumber])))`: count the total of unique filtered emails.

[image]